# slideuppanel functionality like Hot or Not app android

Tags: android

I want to create a Slide up panel library. 
I found https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel. But i want to slide any where on the screen.
I want slide functionality like "Hot or Not" application

Comment: Are you talking about swipe-to-discard kind of cards?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should go for fragments and show them here is a very powerful tutorial by [androidgreeve blog](http://androidgreeve.blogspot.com/2014/02/android-navigation-drawer-sliding-menu.html%20and) 
make sure you go for fragments they are here for you!